# How do I get a Vue.JS project to work when hosted on a server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a new VueJS project using the Vue UI. This runs locally on http://localhost:8080/ with no errors. In addition, all is fine when I run the build task. However, when I take the files that are built and placed inside the dist folder and uploaded these to my hosting package via FTP I get a blank HTML page and the source code is as follows. Clearly not the as my local host.

Just to note I have tried this on two different hosting packages and I get the same result. Any help welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
    <link href=/css/app.deed7380.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=/js/app.1e49a2f5.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/js/chunk-vendors.0e42f062.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/css/app.deed7380.css rel=stylesheet>
    <link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=32x32 href=/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png>
    <link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=16x16 href=/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png>
    <link rel=manifest href=/manifest.json>
    <meta name=theme-color content=#4DBA87>
    <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=no>
    <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=default>
    <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-title content=pwap>
    <link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png>
    <link rel=mask-icon href=/img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg color=#4DBA87>
    <meta name=msapplication-TileImage content=/img/icons/msapplication-icon-144x144.png>
    <meta name=msapplication-TileColor content=#000000>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript><strong>We're sorry but pwap doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div class=content-wrapper>
        <div id=app></div>
    </div>
    <script src=/js/chunk-vendors.0e42f062.js></script>
    <script src=/js/app.1e49a2f5.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there errors in the console that might say something is missing or not loaded?

Comment: Are you using vue-router?

Comment: You can use your built versions on your localhost first and check for errors. Is your app hosted at root path (`http://some-url.com/`, not `http://some-url.com/some-custom-path/`) ?

Comment: @GenericUser a get chunk-vendors.0e42f062.js and app.1e49a2f5.js are mssing

Comment: @SølveTornøe No note yet

Comment: I'd take a look in your network tab and see how the files are being loaded. I'm guessing the path it's taking to load those files may be incorrect. I recognize this as an issue I had before and the `src=/js` part is similar to the problem I had. By removing the leading `/` it resolved the file paths.

Comment: @BeniaminH Good spot. I have opened the file after running the build task, in the dist folder, locally and yes it the same blank screen, so that rules out issues with the hosting compatibility.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `/` from the script src: `<script src=js/app.1e49a2f5.js></script>`

Comment: @SølveTornøe On the hosted version, I inspected element, edit as HTML, removed the / so it was src="js/chunk etc and not src="/js/chunk. Then I hold down ctrl, click on link and I am directed to this file instead of it 404ing. However, how do I amend this in my app?

Comment: Assuming that this is from webpack, you can change that behavior in the public path: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/. To prevent this I think you can just set it to an empty string (e.g. `publicPath:''`). I believe the default is `/` which is what's happening here.

Comment: please check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53883932/8172857) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your build files is created with the wrong path to your assets.

In order to remove the prefixing `/` that causes your issue, you have to change the config file `index.js` in the config folder of your project:

from `assetsPublicPath: '/',`

to `assetsPublicPath: '',`

Then, rebuild your app and they should now be gone and your app should now display.

If you are using **Vue UI** to create your app, you have to do the following:

Open your project in Vue UI and navigate to configuration tab. There, you will select "Vue cli" and then you have to remove the `/` in the baseUrl input field(In the Norwegian screenshot below this is the "URL-utgangspunkt" label):

[image]

Comment: I don't have an index.js or a config folder :(

Comment: Don't you have this in your project folder? (Where you copied the dist folder from)

Comment: You can however do a manual removal of the slashes by editing your index.html file. However, this is not optimal.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you were using Vue Ui.

Comment: I don't know enough about it all yet to know there is a difference. I am very new to VueJS, so just getting my head around the basics. Seems odd how you run the build task but then this wouldn't work. Big thank you for tying to help.

Comment: No worries, we all have to start somewhere :D Please take a look at the updated answer. I have not tried this, but I assume this will do the same as the previous answer

Comment: Epic ... sorry for the delay. The run build showing errors, but VueUI just tripped itself up and needed the dist folder deleting and a restart. Your answer works. Thank you for spotting that and helping me. Let me know if you need any design work doing. Only to happy to return the favor.

Comment: Haha, I'm flattered of the offer ^^ This is, however, StackOverflow, It would mean more for me if you return the favor in taking time to help someone else if you see a question you can answer in here :) - If this answer fixed your issue, I'd be glad if you marked it as answered.

Comment: If I wasn't using Vue UI and instead used the terminal to create a working Vue project, how come I don't have an index.js or find the config folder?

Comment: Thank @solveTornoe. I read this documentation the other day. I have just created a vue.config.js at the same level as my package.json file. I was under the impression you created this file with the terminal, as in doing so it may link to other logic, but seem this isnt the case and you just need this js file in your project. May be the documentation should say 'create a new js file called vue.config and place this in the folder next to your package.json file, but ten documentation is not the same a tutorial. Thanks once again for your help. 4 lost hours but I got there.

Comment: I used Vue with a Laravel installation. Maybe the config folder/files come default from there, I am not certain. I'm glad it worked out for you, my dude.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, you create a new js file called vue.config and place it in your project at the same level as your package.json file. Then add the following code to this new js file. The [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) states to include the forward slash '/' however this will retain them and the paths to js & css files etc will still be broken. Therefore, simply update this code as per below. After which you will need to run the build process again. npm run build

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? ''
    : ''
}
```

Comment: The documentation is really misleading and still not improved to reflect this, this answer solved my issue. Thank you @AI-76

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `vue`, you can set this in your `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: '',
    // rest of your config
};
```

Comment: There is no vue.config.js file

Comment: It's not there by default: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/. It's an optional file that lets you apply settings that modify the configuration setup through vue-cli.

Comment: Not sure the reason for the downvote. This is exactly the same result as the accepted answer but without using the graphic user interface. If vue-cli is present then any adjustments to its logic can be done in the known config file, `vue.config.js`.